# Parse XML with unknown elements in C++ and Qt

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I've got an XML document that I receive from a REST service that I wish to parse. The service might change their element and tag names so I'm trying to come up with some completely generic solution that saves the document structure as some kind of object with attributes.

I'm not sure how/if the C++ and Qt API's allow me to accomplish such a thing however. I've thought of creating some kind of keyed map that can hold element names as string keys and values would be their children in some recursive fashion. Being very new to Qt and C++ I'm not sure how I can accomplish this.

This could be an example XML document:

```
<root>
  <element id="1">
    <name>SomeName</name>
    <desc>SomeDesc</desc>
    <params>
      <param pid="1">True</param>
      <param pid="2">False</param>
    </params>
    ...
    <Some unknown element></Some unknown element>
  </element>
</root>
```

This is how I convert the HTTP response (*QNetworkReply*) to a DOM document I can use in Qt:

```
   QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
   QDomDocument doc;
   doc.setContent(data);
   QDomNodeList nodes = doc.elementsByTagName("root");
   if (nodes.size() > 0) {
      // Prints all elements, should be able to save in a map somehow? Perhaps there is a better way?
      qDebug() << nodes.at(0).toElement().text(); 
   }
```

I would love some input on how I can parse this in a way that allows me to keep all information in the XML even without knowing the element, attribute and tag names. Something like this:

```
element = {
  id : 1,
  name : 'SomeName',
  desc : 'SomeDesc',
  params : [{
        pid : 1,
        param : True
      }, {
        pid : 2,
        param : False
      }
  ],
  some unknown element : some unknown values
}
```

Comment: Are you reading the xml from a file or from an HTTP request?

Comment: From an HTTP request using QNetworkRequest `QNetworkRequest`.

Comment: I’m not aware of any existing solution doing this. You’ll need to implement your own structure. However, the structure holding arbitrary XML data would be the received QByteArray holding the XML data, or a QDomDocument. What would the data structure in C++ in give you if you have no idea of the data in it? Do you do XML processing without interpreting at the contained data?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld The point is the data may change and the data will be passed to GUI developers that will update and change their code when the API changes. This is why I want to do it in a very generic way so that I don't have to update the XML parser for each change in the XML. A generic solution will allow me to just pass on whatever data is coming through to the front-end.